# How to XML document tuple list IEnumerable<(Foo, T)> C#

Tags: c#, xml, tuples

I currently have two methods for sending data, and I'm trying to add a cref from the single to the batch sender, but I'm getting a CS1584 XML error. I've tried the auto generated one but that also gives me an error.

This is a trimmed down version of what I currently have.

```
/// <summary>
/// Sends data to default sender.
/// You should prefer to send data in a batch if possible using <seealso cref="SendFooBatchAsync{T}(IEnumerable{(Foo, T)})"/>
/// <summary>
Task SendFooAsync<T>((Foo, T) item)

/// <summary>
/// Sends batch data to default sender.
/// <summary>
Task SendFooBatchAsync<T>(IEnumerable<(Foo, T)> items)
```

Comment: Can you share the relevant code?

Comment: XML serialization does not support an array at the root.   I can't tell from your posted code if the results will produce more than one object at the root.   If you have more than one object at root you will need to add another class at the top of your current structure so you will have only one object at the root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There currently isn't any XML support for what I am trying to do. Best case would be to expand the syntax of IEnumerable<(Foo, T)> to IEnumerable<Tuple<Foo, T>>.

You can write the cref for this as

```
<seealso cref="SendFooBatchAsync{T}(IEnumerable{Tuple{Foo, T}})"/>
```